# Get list of transactions by date range in Authorize.net

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorize.net

I have been trying to get the list of transactions by date range but couldn't find any API related to Authorize.net

I found [transaction list](https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/index.html#transaction-reporting-get-transaction-list).

Is there any way to get a list by date range or any other custom parameters (except `transaction_id`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [getSettledBatchListRequest](https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/index.html#transaction-reporting-get-settled-batch-list) to get the batch IDs for the date range you wish to get a list of transactions for. Then call [getTransactionListRequest](https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/index.html#transaction-reporting-get-transaction-list) in a loop and get the transactions for each batch.